# Comparing objects in Java

Tags: java

In my AP Computer Science Class we are working on a lab that has us create an array of Monster Objects with the parameters Height, Weight, and Age. We need to print out the Array, print out the largest and the smallest, and then sort the array. I am struggling with comparing the Height of two objects. instead of returning the object, it returns null. Here is my main class file.

```
package lab64;
import static java.lang.Integer.parseInt;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Monsterz 
{
    static String MONSTER;
    static Monster MONSTERS[];
    static int HT;
    static int WT;
    static int AGE;

    /* public Monsterz(int ht, int wt, int age)
    {
    } */

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        MONSTER = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input number of monsters in the herd ::");
        int len = parseInt(MONSTER);
        MONSTERS = new Monster[len];
        for (int i = 0; i <= MONSTERS.length - 1; i++)
        {
            String Height = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input Ht ::");
            String Weight = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input Wt ::");
            String Age = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input Age ::");
            HT = parseInt(Height);
            WT = parseInt(Weight);
            AGE = parseInt(Age);
            MONSTERS[i] = new Monster(HT,WT,AGE);
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                null, 
                "HERD :: " + Arrays.toString(MONSTERS) + "\nLARGEST :: " + getLargest(), 
                "Monster Lab", 
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

    } 
    public static Monster getLargest()
    {
        Monster largest = null;
        for(int c = 0; c > MONSTERS.length; c++)
        {
            if (MONSTERS[c].getHeight() > MONSTERS[c+1].getHeight())
            {
               largest = MONSTERS[c];
            }
        }
        return largest;
    }


}
```

and here is the Monster class file

```
package lab64;
class Monster {

    int ht = 0;
    int wt = 0;
    int age = 0;
    Monster(int HT, int WT, int AGE) 
    {
        ht = HT;
        wt = WT;
        age = AGE;

    }
    public int getHeight()
    {
        return ht;
    }
    public int getWeight()
    {
        return wt;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return ht + " " + wt + " " + age;
    }

}
```

How can i fix this to make it work?

Comment: Try to avoid using uppercase names for variable variables. Most people use uppercase for constants.

Answer (score 2):

Correct your for condition.

Change `for(int c = 0; c > MONSTERS.length; c++)`

to

`for(int c = 0; c < MONSTERS.length; c++)`

Also correct the logic for finding the largest element in the array:

```
    Monster largest = MONSTERS[0];
    for(int c = 0; c < MONSTERS.length; c++)
    {
        if (largest.getHeight() > MONSTERS[c].getHeight())
        {
           largest = MONSTERS[c];
        }
    }
```